# Files are repeated when uploading pictures to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do bulk image upload on my blog that I write in Laravel. Wrote the code for loading images. Everything works, but the images are repeated

```
$images = [];
$urls = [];

if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
    foreach($request->file('images') as $key => $image){
        $images[] = Storage::putFile('public/' . Auth::user()->id . '/post', $image);
        foreach($images as $img) {
            $urls[] = Storage::url($img);
        }
    }
    $post->post_images = serialize($urls);
}
```

After loading 6 images, I get this array of 21 elements. What's wrong?

Comment: Put your second foreach outside the first one. Every time you add an image you're rerunning the `foreach($images as $img)` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending `$images` to `$urls` on **each image**. Do it like this instead, appending images to `$urls` **after** all images are processed:

```
$images = [];
$urls = [];

if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
    foreach($request->file('images') as $key => $image){
        $images[] = Storage::putFile('public/' . Auth::user()->id . '/post', $image);
    }
    foreach($images as $img) {
        $urls[] = Storage::url($img);
    }
    $post->post_images = serialize($urls);
}
```